# Where does this step into solving an equation come from?

Tags: calculus

I know this might sound dumb, but becuause I am a "beginner" i have this doubt a long time ago, and I would like a complete exlpanation about why it is possible to do it. And most because I have seen that too many physicists use it.

---

It is about the following step involving solving this problem:
$$ \dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$$
$$ \Rightarrow df(x)=\dfrac{dx}{x} $$
$$ \Rightarrow f(x)=ln(x)+k $$ being k a constant.
It is just because of the first and second fundamental calculus theorem? But what happen if I work with several variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from:
$$\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$$
you could say you then integrate both sides with respect to $x$, that is:
$$\color{blue}{\int} \dfrac{df(x)}{dx} \,\color{blue}{dx}=\color{blue}{\int}\dfrac{1}{x}\,\color{blue}{dx}$$
Now the left-hand side is, due to the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\int \dfrac{df(x)}{dx} \, dx = \int f'(x) \, dx = f(x) \quad(+C)$$
You can integrate the right-hand side with the usual rules for integration.

In practice, more particularly in the context of differential equations, the following notation is often used when applying *separation of variables*. Split the $y=f(x)$ and the $x$ parts as you wrote it and follow up with "integrating both sides":
$$\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x} \quad\rightarrow\quad df(x)=\dfrac{1}{x} dx \quad\rightarrow\quad \color{blue}{\int}df(x)=\color{blue}{\int}\dfrac{1}{x} dx$$

Take a look at Wikipedia's [Separation of varibales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

What exactly do you mean with the situation of more variables?

Comment: A function defined as $f:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m $, i mean how far does this "trick" work, when working with several variables I would need to consider several integrations?

Comment: This is still a bit vague. If the functions involved are functions of more variables, then you're probable no longer dealing with _ordinary differential equations_ but with _partial differential equations_: the entire process of solving becomes more complicated. There is however a technique that is also based on separating variables, but the independent ones. More info on that as well on the wiki-page I mentioned in the answer.